# Validating Multiple Fields (Datetime and Bool) in Data Annotation Model on Submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, data-annotations

Currently I'm working on a MVC 3 Environment and I need to add a Validation that validates 2 Fields in Dataannotation Models just like the validation of `[Required(ErrorMessage="Required!")]` that is triggered onsubmit.

Currently , The Validation `[Required]` is working but i need to check if the `bool` and `dateTime` Datatype

Heres the Code in my Model

```
public class NameInfo: IValidatableObject
    {

        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
        public string Name{ get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public Nullable<DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Already Starting")]
        public bool IsStarting{ get; set; }


        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (!IsStarting&& !StartDate.HasValue)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Required.", new[] { "StartDate" });

            }  
        }
    }
```

Currently im using `IValidatableObject` but its not validating unless the `name` Field modelstate is already Valid

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Are you want to ensure that if `IsStarting` is `true` then `StartDate` must have a value?

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes, because this two fields are connected to each other, if  `IsStarting` is `false` and `StartDate` is `null` then the validation will be shown

Comment: Forget the `IValidatableObject`. Look at using a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfTrue]` or similar attribute (and its easy enough to write your own). That way you get both client side and server side validation

Comment: @StephenMuecke is this an addon?

Comment: @StephenMuecke if this is an addon, I'm not allowed to use an addtional addon to the project that ive been working on

Comment: foolproof is (you can download the nuget package). But there are plenty of example of how to write your own.

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you supply some examples, been searching for 1 hour and tried it all , yet none of them worked

Comment: I have my own, so I will post it (need a break so give me 30 min or so)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks man, will wait your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently im using IValidatableObject but its not validating unless
>   the name Field modelstate is already Valid

`DataAnnotations` and `IValidatableObject` will not validate together. What I mean by that is the `IValidatableObject`'s validate method will only be called if your `DataAnnotations` are valid.

Either write your own `ValdiationAttribute` or add the required validation to your `IValidatableObject`.

Here is an example of the latter...

```
public class NameInfo : IValidatableObject
{

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public Nullable<DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Already Starting")]
    public bool IsStarting { get; set; }


    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Name is required!");
        }


        if (!IsStarting && !StartDate.HasValue)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Required.", new[] { "StartDate" });

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, Gonna try this, Thanks!

Comment: definitely this work but can it refreshes the page upon showing the validation, will this work without post back? Thanks